# Function for the focal method

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to run a simple function using focal which takes 5 random values within each window and then computes the coefficient of variance (sd/mean) from those values. Code below which is currently returning the error: *Evaluation error: invalid first argument.*

```
library(raster)

# Create random raster
x <- raster(ncol=360, nrow=180, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)
values(x) <- runif(ncell(x))

cv= function(x,...){
  y = na.omit(sample(x, size=5, replace =F))
  sd(y)/mean(y)
}

foc = focal(x = x , w = matrix(nrow=5,ncol=5), fun = cv)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this. Here using "terra" (the replacement of the now obsolete "raster" package)

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(ncol=50, nrow=50, xmin=0, xmax=100, ymin=0, ymax=100)
values(x) <- 1:ncell(x)

cv <- function(x){
  y <- na.omit(sample(x, size=5, replace =F))
  sd(y) / mean(y)
}

f <- focal(x, w=5, fun = cv)
```

If you want to use a matrix intead as argument `w`, then the matrix should not  only have `NA`s as in your example `w=matrix(nrow=5,ncol=5)`. Normally you would set all values to 1, unless you wanted to exclude some cells. For example, to make a circle. You can do:

```
f <- focal(x, w=matrix(1,5,5), fun = cv)
```